# fullcalendar draggable events easing on remaining DIVs

Tags: jquery, events, draggable, external, slideup

http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/external-dragging.html

On the above demo of fullcalendar where external events from a separate DIV (sidebar) are draggable and droppable to the calendar, when the box "remove after drop" is ticked, a dragged event is removed from the list after dropping it to the calendar. I would like to add an easing or similar effect to the other DIVs that are left in the draggable events sidebar when an event is removed, so that the viewer will know that something was removed from the list. Is there a jquery way to slide up the remaining items (DIVs) below an item that was removed so that if I drag event 3 to the calendar, events 4 and 5 will move up, with event 4 taking the place of event 3, and event 5 taking the place of event 4? How do I do it? Please explain to a noob. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

demo uses this code to remove the dropped event

```
 // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
    $(this).remove();
}
```

Change `$(this).remove()` to:

```
$(this).slideUp(function(){
     $(this).remove();
 });
```

The slideUp() method will animate a collapse of the event in list

jQuery API Ref: http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Comment: sorry, I'm so noob I didn't even have the presence of mind to accept your answer. Answer accepted now and thanks again.